# Scrapy tutorial (noob) - 0 pages crawled

Tags: python, scrapy, data-extraction

I've been trying to follow the Scrapy tutorial (as in, very very beginning) and after running the command at the project top level (i.e. the level with scrapy.cfg) I get the following output:

```
 mikey@ubuntu:~/scrapy/tutorial$ scrapy crawl dmoz
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/settings/deprecated.py:26: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: You are using the following settings which are deprecated or obsolete (ask scrapy-users@googlegroups.com for alternatives):
    BOT_VERSION: no longer used (user agent defaults to Scrapy now)
  warnings.warn(msg, ScrapyDeprecationWarning)
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS': 'tutorial.items.TutorialItem', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'tutorial/1.0', 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [dmoz] INFO: Spider opened
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [dmoz] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-01-26 04:17:06-0800 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/> (referer: None)
2014-01-26 04:17:07-0800 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/> (referer: None)
2014-01-26 04:17:07-0800 [dmoz] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-01-26 04:17:07-0800 [dmoz] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 472,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 14888,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 26, 12, 17, 7, 63261),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 26, 12, 17, 6, 567929)}
2014-01-26 04:17:07-0800 [dmoz] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
mikey@ubuntu:~/scrapy/tutorial$
```

(I.e. 0 pages crawled at 0/a second!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)

Troubleshooting so far:
1) Checked syntax of both items.py and dmoz_spider.py (both copied and pasted AND hand-typed)
2) Checked for problem online but cannot see others with similar issue
3) Checked folder structure etc making sure running command from correct place
4) Upgraded to latest version of scrapy

Any suggestions? My code is precisely as in the examples

dmoz_spider.py is......

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

and items.py......

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class DmozItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    desc = Field()
```

Comment: you probably have typo somewhere, paste you code here

Comment: So... posting code down in comments didn't go well for me so I have edited post @Guy

Comment: your spider crawled 2 pages `'response_received_count': 2`, and since you're writing the pages' HTML body to a local file, you should have them in your project with the HTML content. But your spider is not grabbing any items (the first part of the Scrapy tutorial is not a real useful usecase). Continue the tutorial to http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#using-our-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should **find out what you want to crawl**.

You passed the two start urls to scrapy, so it crawled them, but could not find more urls to follow.

All book links on that page are not meeting allowed_domains `dmoz.org`.

You can do `yield Request([next url])` to crawl more links, `next url` can be parsed from response.

Or inherit CrawlSpider and specify rules like [this example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example).

Answer (score 1):

this line is printed recurrently, first when the spider is opened, there is no problem in your code, you just didn't implement anything else yet

Answer (score 0):

You have to `yield` an item in order to save it and then you have to `yield Request(<next_url>)` to move to the new page.

You can check this blog for getting started with scrapy

https://www.inkoop.io/blog/web-scraping-using-python-and-scrapy/